# How to get related data from MySQL using a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, laravel

On a Laravel 10 site I remake repositories when all eloquent read/write methods must be replaced with MySQL stored procedures. I have a method:

```
public function get(int $id): Task
{
    $task = Task::getById($id)
        ->with('creator')
        ->with('parentTask')
        ->with('category')
        ->with('taskUsers')
        ->with('taskUsers.user')
        ->firstOrFail();
```

In a repository with stored procedure I have :

```
public function get(int $id): Task
{
    $model = new Task();
    $task = $model->hydrate(
        DB::select(
            'call sp_taskGet(' . $id . ' )'
        )
    )[0];

    return $task;
```

And sp_taskGet stored procedure defined:

```
create procedure sp_taskGet(IN in_taskId bigint unsigned)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE id = in_taskId;
END;
```

But as I also top get related data like 'creator', 'parentTask'... In which way can I do it in this way ?

```
8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
"laravel/framework": "^10.34.2",
```

Comment: What is the exact error that you get?

Comment: I do not have any errors, just do not know how to make it

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are all read/write methods required to be re-implemented in stored procedures? MySQL stored procedures are a bad implementation. Poor performance, no debugger, no atomic deployment, no support for packages, etc. Virtually everything one can do in a stored procedure is faster and easier in client code.

Comment: My team lead is only mysql developer and he want to edit requests on his own

Comment: I've not yet called SP's from Laravel, but you may possibly need `DB::selectRaw` instead.

Comment: Interpolating variables into a query string? Bad idea.